# How do I prevent X11 from setting opost for tty7?

Tags: linux, graphics, terminal, x11

Good day:

My Ubuntu 16.04.1 machine with i915 graphics has the following settings for tty2:

speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
-brkint -imaxbel iutf8

whilst the settings for tty7 (the terminal for X11 are)

speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
min = 1; time = 0;
ignbrk -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke

Probably X11/lightdm produces those settings for tty7 during xinit/startx. How can I change the terminal settings produced by X11/lightdm for tty?

Cheers,

Dani

Answer (score 0):

If X is running on tty7, you would not be using it for a shell login.  But you can change the terminal attributes (whether it is helpful or not depends on the use you make of it).

Assuming you have permissions, e.g., running as **root**:

```
stty opost </dev/tty7
```

That is, the redirection opens a valid file descriptor on the terminal.  You might see something like this:

```
$ sudo su -
[sudo] password for whoever: 
# stty -a </dev/tty7
speed 38400 baud; rows 25; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
ignbrk -brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
-echoctl -echoke
# stty opost </dev/tty7
# stty -a </dev/tty7
speed 38400 baud; rows 25; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
ignbrk -brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
-echoctl -echoke
```

Comment: I actually want to hinder X11 from producing tty settings in the first place. I am not into a "stty -F /dev/tty7 sane" command after X11 having produced its tty settings. Any suggestions as to where I can find the right switch?